# How to delete a job started with LimitRunsTo(1) option while using github.com/go-co-op/gocron?

Tags: go

In this program I am using github.com/go-co-op/gocron package. I am adding a job with tag 'oneTimeJob' and using option LimitRunsTo(1). The package documentation says that the job will run only once but will stay on scheduler. However, once the job has run I can neither delete the job nor I can add a new job with same tag. Please see the code below.

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "time"

        "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
)

var s1 *gocron.Scheduler

func taskWithParams(a int, b string, isMono bool) {
    fmt.Println(a, b)
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("Cron taskWithParams tag %s ran at %s\n", b, t.Local())
    if isMono == true {
        fmt.Println("This is an one time job")
    }
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("Go launched at %s\n", t.Local())

    // defines a new scheduler that schedules and runs jobs
    s1 = gocron.NewScheduler(time.Local)
    s1.TagsUnique()
    s1.StartAsync()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for {
        fmt.Print("Enter add for adding job, rem for removing job, run for running a job: ")
        var option string
        var cronString string
        var tag        string
        scanner.Scan()
        option = scanner.Text()
        switch option {
        case "add":
                fmt.Print("Enter crontab: ")
                scanner.Scan()
                cronString = scanner.Text()
                fmt.Print("Enter tag: ")
                scanner.Scan()
                tag = scanner.Text()
                job, err := s1.Cron(cronString).Tag(tag).LimitRunsTo(1).Do(taskWithParams, 1, tag, true)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    break
                }
                t = time.Now()
                fmt.Printf("Cron job with tag %s added at %s\n", job.Tags(), t.Local())
        case "rem":
                fmt.Print("Enter tag to delete: ")
                scanner.Scan()
                tag = scanner.Text()
                err := s1.RemoveByTag(tag)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    break
                }
                fmt.Println("Remaining number of jobs ", s1.Len())
        case "run":
                fmt.Print("Enter tag to run:" )
                scanner.Scan()
                tag = scanner.Text()
                s1.RunByTag(tag)
        default:
                fmt.Print("invalid option chosen \n")
        }
    }
    s1.Clear()
    s1.Stop()
}
```

Here is the output of the run:

```
$ go run gocronWithIo.go
Go launched at 2021-08-12 00:53:43.0323366 +0530 IST
Enter add for adding job, rem for removing job, run for running a job: add
Enter crontab: 58 00 * * *
Enter tag: oneTimeJob
Cron job with tag [oneTimeJob] added at 2021-08-12 00:57:18.2042977 +0530 IST
Enter add for adding job, rem for removing job, run for running a job: 1 oneTimeJob
Cron taskWithParams tag oneTimeJob ran at 2021-08-12 00:58:00.0074596 +0530 IST
This is an one time job
rem
Enter tag to delete: oneTimeJob
no jobs found with given tag >>>>> I can't remove the job
Enter add for adding job, rem for removing job, run for running a job: add
Enter crontab: 00 10 * * *
Enter tag: oneTimeJob
a non-unique tag was set on the job: oneTimeJob >>>>> I can't add the job either.
```

Am I handling LimitRunsTo(1) option incorrectly? What is the correct way to remove this job?

I am using version gocron v1.6.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

```
// LimitRunsTo limits the number of executions of this job to n.
// Upon reaching the limit, the job is removed from the scheduler.
```

Because it is fired immediately upon addition, it no longer exists when you try to remove it.

Comment: In that case why does it error out when I try to add a new job with same tag 'oneTimeJob'? Please note that I configure the scheduler with TagsUnique().

Comment: From what i see in the code, it could be a bug. [RemoveByTag](https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron/blob/f46e4903c53f530bb336026abb86dfb3bc7a928d/scheduler.go#L535) method does not reach the line on which the tag is removed from the uniqueness map when job does not exist.

Comment: Hey all, looks like an issue was opened for this and we addressed it! I didn't think to monitor stack overflow for gocron issues but I will now! https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron/issues/210